# android context & launch mode

Tags: android, android-context

I have a `StartActivity` which displays a full screen image and navigate to other activities after about 3 secs.

In this activity, I do some initializing work that is related to `Context`. For example `AccountManager.init(context)`,`DatabaseHelper.init(context)`.

Now the problem: when I jump from the `StartActivity` to `MainActivity`, if I finish `StartActivity`, will cause `AccountManager` and `DatabaseHelper` throw `NullPointerException` on reaching its context.If I don't finish `StartActivity`, pressing back key in `MainActivity` will jump back to `StartActivity` and start over.

Any suggestion on this ? If I can control the navigation between these activities by setting launch mode (instead of getting nullpointer exception, I'd rather keep this `StartActivity`)?

Comment: Use application context.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Application context instead. You can get it in any `Activity` by calling [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()).

Comment: But there will still be a problem if I show an alert dialog in those application-context-initialized class. Perhaps the best idea is to change the structure of my code ? Lot of background task using `Context` in my application.

Comment: You might want to use [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

use ApplicationContext for cross activities  operations e.g Sqlite datasource , starting Servies ,AsyncTasks ,..
and use acticity context for activity UI